# How to send server error request when ever error happen in Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular2-services, angular9, angular-errorhandler

I have a global error Interceptor which handles the error when server return error response. I have error interceptor to handle that.

In my use case whenever an error occurs in angular app , consider server send a response of 200 and  in the response one of the property is missing, so angular app will break and have an error in console.  Is there any better way to handle any error to make the server call?

Comment: its hard to figure out what you are asking. why does the "app break"? can you just code it so the app doesn't break?

Comment: @Rick my question is simple, whenever error occurs in client side , need to send error server request to send the stack trace. in above point i have given some exaple scenario , consider there is username property in missing from the response ,it will get undefined error in angular app , so in that case i have to send server call.

Comment: hopefully someone else can help. Without seeing any code, its hard for me to tell you what code should be changed. but yes, it should be easy to code an angular app that handles both server and app errors nicely, without breaking the app.